# How query and response for API NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to query and response for API. I have 2 collections "Account" and "User". "User" has "id" field and "Account" has "user_id" field - both of us is one. One "User" has one or many Account and it has "id" field in "Account" collection. I want to query "id" from "User" collection and expect the result detail of this User and 1 field "accounts_id" into it.

This is all my expected result to look like: 
https://sample-accounts-api.herokuapp.com/

I tried to collect "accounts_id" but I can not know how to query and add it to "User" detail.

This is my collect "accounts_id":

```
exports.findAllAccountIDforUser = (req, res) => {
    Account
    .find({user_id: req.param('user_id')})
    .then(result => {
        let a = result.map(data => {
            return data.id;
        })
        res.send({'accounts_id':a});

    })
}
```

My "User" Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const Account = require('../model/account');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: {type: Number, unique: true},
        name: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

My "Account" Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: {type: Number},
        user_id: {type: Number, ref: 'User'},
        name: String,
        balance: Number
});


const Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

module.exports = Account;
```

Answer (score 0):

using async-await you can do it in 4 lines.

- get user
- get all accounts related to that user
- assign user.account_ids=accounts
- send response.

  ```
   exports.findAllAccountIDforUser = async(req, res) => {
      let user=await User.findOne({id:req.param('user_id')});
      let accounts= await Account.find({user_id: req.param('user_id')}).select(' _id id);
      user.account_ids=accounts;
      res.send(user);
     }
  ```

another way is using promises like you are already doing it.

```
exports.findAllAccountIDforUser = (req, res) => {
 User
 .findOne({id:req.param('user_id')})
  .then(user=>{
    Account
    .find({user_id: req.param('user_id')})
    .then(result => {
        let a = result.map(data => {
            return data.id;
        })
       user.account_ids=a;
        res.send(user);

    })
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for thís:

```
exports.findAlldetail = (req, res) => {
   User
   .aggregate([
       {
           $match: {
                id: +req.param('id')}
        },
       {
           $lookup: {
                from: "accounts",
                localField: "id",
                foreignField: "user_id",
                as: "account_ids"
            }
        },
       {    
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                id: 1,
                name: 1,
                "account_ids.id": 1
            }
       }
   ])
   .then(result => {
        result.account_ids = result.map(data => {
            data.account_ids = data.account_ids.map(b => b.id);
         })
        res.send({"attributes":result});
   })
}
```